# Analytic lower bounds on the first sign change of pi(x) - li(x)?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-number-theory

There have been many results on the first sign change of $\pi(x)-{\mathrm{li}}(x)$: among others, Lehman, te Riele, Bays & Hudson, Demichael, Chao & Plymen, and most recently Saouter & Demichel.  These provide upper bounds (as well as lower bounds on some region in which $\pi(x)>{\mathrm{li}}(x)$).

Could these methods be used to generate a lower bound?  That is, a region [2, y] in which $\pi(x)<{\mathrm{li}}(x)$.  (Or even a region [x, y] where y is smaller than the best known upper bound, such that, in principle at least, direct calculations could yield a lower bound.)

It seems unlikely that direct searches like [2] will ever be able to resolve the exact value of the first crossing.

---

[1] C. Bays and R. H. Hudson. "[A new bound for the smallest x with $\pi(x)>{\mathrm{li}}(x)$](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2000-69-231/S0025-5718-99-01104-7/)" *Mathematics of Computation* **69** (2000), pp. 1285–1296.

[2] T. Kotnik. "[The prime-counting function and its analytic approximations](http://lbk.fe.uni-lj.si/pdfs/aicm2008.pdf)", *Advances in Computational Mathematics* **29** (2008), pp. 55-70.

[2] R. Sherman Lehman. "[On the difference $\pi(x)-{\mathrm{li}}(x)$](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa11/aa11132.pdf)" *Acta Arithmetica* **11** (1965), pp. 397–410.

[3] H. J. J. te Riele. "[On the sign of the difference $\pi(x)-{\mathrm{li}}(x)$](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1987-48-177/S0025-5718-1987-0866118-6/S0025-5718-1987-0866118-6.pdf)" *Mathematics of Computation* **48** (1987), pp. 323–328.

[4] Yannick Saouter and Patrick Demichel. "[A sharp region where $\pi(x)-{\mathrm{li}}(x)$ is positive](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2010-79-272/S0025-5718-10-02351-3/home.html)" *Mathematics of Computation* **79** (2010), pp. 2395-2405.

Comment: Just to be clear: is the lower limit of your definition of $\mathrm{li}$ 0 (i.e., Cauchy principal value integral) or 2?

Comment: @J. M.: I was taking the Cauchy principal value where li(2) = 1.045..., but I would be interested in an answer to either, provided of course that x >= 8 to avoid small answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some explicit results in the work S. B. Stechkin, A. Yu. Popov, “The asymptotic distribution of prime numbers on the average”, Uspekhi Mat. Nauk, 51:6(312) (1996), 21–88

Comment: Thank you. I found the translation S. B. Stechkin and A. Yu Popov, Russ. Math. Surv. 51 (1996), pp. 1025-1092. 