# About sign changes of Li(x)-π(x)

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Given a constant $C$, which are the best known *upper* bounds for the number of sign changes
of the function
$$
  f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ \ x \mapsto {\rm Li}(x)-\pi(x)
$$
in the range $1 \leq x \leq C$?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48461/analytic-lower-bounds-on-the-first-sign-change-of-pix-lix/112068#112068

Comment: The OP has clarified that the question is not asking for bounds on the first sign change of ${\rm Li}(x) - \pi(x)$, and is hence not a mere duplicate. I have tried to improve the formulation of the question, and voted to reopen.

Comment: Are you familiar with the results of Kaczorowski? See Theorem 1 of http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa45/aa4517.pdf

Comment: The result @so-calledfriendDon mentions is a lower bound. (That OP wants upper bounds only was not really visible when that comment was made.)

Comment: @quid: o.k. -- I noticed this, but have chosen the more general formulation since upper bounds may be delicate. -- At least I guess that once there is a sign change, there might be a whole lot of sign changes which are very close together(?)

Comment: @StefanKohl I see. But Hamed was explicit about *not* being interested in lower bounds (while this being I think the 'default' interpretation) and thus I think this information should be preserved somehow.

Comment: Thank u, Stefan.Thanks to all. I saw your article, so_called friend. I havent seen it.(very good) But as quid said I need an upper bound.Actually, I need aan upper bound less than x^a(a is real). I feel there exists. But I cant prove it.