# Does $\pi(x) \geq \mathrm{Li}(x)$ imply that $\vartheta(x) \geq x$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem

As the question in the title asks, does $\pi(x) \geq \mathrm{Li}(x)$ imply that $\vartheta(x) \geq x$? Here $\pi(x) = \#\{p \leq x\}$, $\vartheta(x) = \sum_{p \leq x} \log p$ and $\mathrm{Li}(x) = \int_{2}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t}$.

Alternatively, is there a number $x$ such that $\pi(x) \geq \mathrm{Li}(x)$ and $\vartheta(x) \leq x$, or a number $x$ such that $\pi(x) \leq \mathrm{Li}(x)$ and $\vartheta(x) \geq x$?

Comment: It might help for non-experts in prime number theory to recall what $\theta(x)$ is.

Comment: My gut feeling is that the implication in the title is not true, but what do I know :P

Comment: You can find different information about error terms from these two problems in the article S. B. Stechkin, A. Yu. Popov, “The asymptotic distribution of prime numbers on the average”, Uspekhi Mat. Nauk, 51:6(312) (1996), 21–88. See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/48461/analytic-lower-bounds-on-the-first-sign-change-of-pix-lix/112068#112068